# Level of Data Security in iOS

Tags: firewalls, ios

How secure is the data stored on iOS devices, specifically app data like notes, pictures, etc.?  Are there any ways to make it more secure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the app you are using asks for Data Protection, they are only as secure as your device is.  Most data is stored relatively in the clear and could be pulled off the device easily with physical access to a functional device.  Even with Data Protection, it is only as secure as your pin or password.  According to [this](http://www.zdziarski.com/blog/?p=2149) article, most apps don't use Data Protection yet.

This also doesn't take in to consideration any possible issues that could arise from either intentional or unintentional leaking of data off the device by the apps that you are using (such as cloud backups and the like.)